# Create a struct with template which get pointers of others struct

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, struct

I want to create a balanced tree. It works for a custom struct so I wanted to improve my balanced tree by using a template to create a tree which contains any type. And there is my issue :

```
template <typename T>
struct Branch {
    float index;
    T value;
    Branch *inf = nullptr;
    Branch *sup = nullptr;
    Branch *parent = nullptr;
};
```

Because it is a balanced tree, each branch has is index, and has a pointer to its parent branch, and pointers to their two children branches.
But I can't compile this code, i get a C2079 error which says that "Branch::value uses a classof 'T' not defined".
I use VS2017RC.

==EDIT==

I locate the issue in my class Tree :

```
template <class T>
class Tree {
public:
    /**/
private:
    Branch<T>* _origine; //Initialized in constructor Tree() to nullptr
    Branch<T> _branches[1000]; //Here is the error
    /**/
};
```

So the problem is this static array of Branch, but I have no idea on how I can initialize it ...

Thanks for any answer !

Comment: Please post the code where you're instantiating the template.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: [OT]: `float index;`look strange for me.

Comment: @molbdnilo I updated the question with the code where is the instantiation

Answer (score 1):

I donot see any problem with your code. I compiled it using `g++ -std=c++11` without any error. I used

```
int main() { Branch<int> b; }
```

to instantiate the template class.

MSDN mentions the error C2079 when class has only forward declarations or not visible. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ekhdcxs.aspx. The possible solution mentioned here is use pointer for T and forward declare the type T or include the definition of T. 
Posting the code for instantiation will surely help.
Posting the code for

Comment: I update the question with the code including the instantiation in the Tree class (in a static array). Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

You are likely missing template argument. You should use like this:

```
Branch<int> bint;
Branch<float> bfloat;
```

So you can access value with the right type

```
bint.value = 42;
bfloat.value = 42f;
```